# Installing Xdebug for use in VS Code 1.2.1

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, version, xdebug

The choices for Xdebug are too many! I am running MAMP PHP version 7.1.5 and am on a Windows 7.0 machine running VS Code 1.2.1.

How do I know which version of Xdebug to download and install? There seems to be a variety of choices for all the PHP versions from 5 through 7.

How does one know which version of PHP 7 to use on a 64bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

- go to XDebug.com and on the webpage menubar
- click on Documentation on the menu, then find 'Installation' on the webpage list
- click on 'Installation',
- find the Compiling section, click on the 'Wizard' link
- paste the phpinfo for your computer's installation of php (I used MAMP,
  phpinfo  the php function produces a webpage of output to cut and
  paste into the wizard's input. see image.
- click the 'analyze my phpinfo()' button at the bottom of the page
- the output is detailed instructions on all the steps and choices to
  make for your version of php.

[image]